Why does the Excel SEQUENCE function have trouble with 1D arrays passed to its [start] parameter?
Consider the following two formulae, which appear (to me) like they should return the same result:
=SEQUENCE(5,,1,)

=SEQUENCE(5,,{1},)

The first will yield the expected result: ={1;2;3;4;5} The second does not; it simply yields the value 1. However, if you press F9 in the cell, it WILL result in ={1;2;3;4;5}. I have resolved this issue using INDEX, since the following works:
=SEQUENCE(5,,INDEX({1},1,1),)

I have consistently run into this as an issue when defining LAMBDA functions involving SEQUENCE (where I was not passing a literal array, but some previously defined variable that was a length 1 array), and initially I found it quite frustrating to debug. Now I know to look out for it, but I am bothered that it is an issue at all. I want to understand WHY this happens - was it intended, or is it a bug? What is the root cause?
I am also thinking about this post as a kind of PSA, in case others run into this problem. I could not find anyone else discussing this when I did some googling, although I did find a similar issue that was related to how array formulae used to be created (when Shift Ctrl Enter was required), linked below.
https://www.excelforum.com/excel-formulas-and-functions/1144391-formula-result-using-f9-is-different-than-what-is-displayed-in-the-cell.html
EDIT:
@FlexYourData has inspired me to define the following:
=LAMBDA(rows,[columns],[from],[to],[by_col],
IFS(
OR(ROWS(rows)<>1, COLUMNS(rows)<>1, rows<>ROUND(rows,0), rows<=0),
"Argument 'rows' must be a positive integer",
IF(NOT(ISOMITTED(columns)), OR(ROWS(columns)<>1, COLUMNS(columns)<>1, columns<>ROUND(columns,0), columns<=0), FALSE()),
"Argument 'columns' must be a positive integer",
IF(NOT(ISOMITTED(from)), OR(ROWS(from)<>1, COLUMNS(from)<>1), FALSE()),
"Argument 'from' must be a scalar",
IF(NOT(ISOMITTED(to)), OR(ROWS(to)<>1, COLUMNS(to)<>1), FALSE()),
"Argument 'to' must be a scalar",
IF(NOT(ISOMITTED(by_col)), OR(ROWS(by_col)<>1, COLUMNS(by_col)<>1, AND(by_col<>0, by_col<>1)), FALSE()),
"Argument 'by_col' must be a boolean",
TRUE(),
LET(
final_rows,@rows,
final_columns,IF(ISOMITTED(columns),1,@columns),
size,final_rows*final_columns,
final_from,IF(ISOMITTED(from),1,@from),
final_to,IF(ISOMITTED(to),final_from+size-1,@to),
final_by_col,IF(ISOMITTED(by_col),0,@by_col),
IF(final_by_col,
TRANSPOSE(SEQUENCE(final_columns,final_rows,final_from,(final_to-final_from)/(size-1))),
SEQUENCE(final_rows,final_columns,final_from,(final_to-final_from)/(size-1))
)
)
)
)


I prefer these arguments to the standard ones and this should avoid the issue which motivated this post. Feel free to critique or improve, everyone.

Very interesting question. The short answer is those parameters expect scalar arguments, so arrays must be coerced to scalars for the function to work as expected.
I don't have a good answer beyond that right now, but I will try to find out.
For now, I want to note that you can also coerce the 1x1 array to a scalar with the single operator @. Warning message aside, this produces the array as expected:
=SEQUENCE(5,,@{1},)


And is applicable to variables:
=LET(_start, {1}, SEQUENCE(5,,@_start,))

Your call to INDEX with row and column 1 is doing the same thing - converting the array to a scalar.
While I try to find more information (no guarantee I'll find anything more enlightening, but I'll try), let me put out an open question:
What would you expect the result of this formula to be?
=SEQUENCE(5,,{1, 2},)

Or this?
=SEQUENCE(5,,SEQUENCE(2,2),)


Very interesting, and great to know about @! I can imagine a setup in which =SEQUENCE(5,,{1, 2},) would return ={1,2;2,3;3,4;4,5;5,6}. But I think this would only make sense if the columns argument was 2 i.e. same length as {1,2}. I can understand why this would be a bit weird for the overall design of the function though, so it doesn't surprise me that arrays don't really work as parameters to [start]. However, if that is the case, then in my mind SEQUENCE should throw some kind of error if it detects an array argument that is not length 1, and it should coerce length 1 arrays to scalars.

@ricewhitlam, a workaround (for now) could be to move the array outside the function: =SEQUENCE(5,,0)+{1,2}. The fun workaround would be to create your own sequence function that accepts arrays. And thanks, Owen, for the great answer!
